# How can I override Google Map's shortest route feature when drag plotting a long scenic route?

Tags: google-maps

Want to use Google Map to plot scenic trip route which is not the shortest distance between start and end destination. Google intercedes with its own route suggestions that are shorter, eventually completely overriding the desired route. Is it possible to turn off this "helpful insistent shortest route" feature of Google Map so any desired route can be plotted?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to turn the feature off if `Measure distance` is acceptable instead:

[image: Measure distance example]

The blue route is Google's suggestion, the black a series of clicks where the hollow black circles are.